# QPalette with multiple color background

Tags: c++, qt

I know that we can use QPalette to set the background for a QLabel. But could I draw a multiple color background with QPalette? For instance, the half above in black and the half below in blue. 
I couldn't find a setRect() function QPalette. Or should I use other class? Or do I have to draw the background with a painter?

Comment: Maybe you could sub class the QLabel and override the paintEvent() function?

Comment: @vahancho Hey you again! Thanks for your comment. I add a drawRect in paintevent(). I think I misunderstood the use of QPalette.

Comment: in palette you can set a `QBrush` with `QPixmap` which will be used as tiles. If image will be big enough you can achieve desired effect. Custom paint give you better control on final result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation for QGradient](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgradient.html) class states:-

> The QGradient class is used in combination with QBrush to specify gradient fills

So, you can start by creating a gradient and setting that to a QBrush

```
QLinearGradient linearGrad(QPointF(100, 100), QPointF(100, 200));
linearGrad.setColorAt(0, Qt::black);
linearGrad.setColorAt(0.5, Qt::blue);
```

You can experiment with setting different colours at different stops, which range from 0.0, to 1.0

Use the gradient to create a brush...

```
QBrush brush(linearGrad);
```

The [documentation for QPalette](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpalette.html) states: -

> Colors and brushes can be set for particular roles in any of a palette's color groups with setColor() and setBrush().

So, using the setBrush function of QPalette, set the brush that is created with the gradient: -

```
QPalette palette;
palette->setBrush(QPalette::Window, brush);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. QGradient is more rich than I expected.